# How do you encrypt a string with BigInteger?

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, biginteger

I am attempting to take an alphanumeric string and encrypt it using big integer. My encryption and decryption work when I initialize BigInteger with a decimal value, such as 10. However when I initialize BigInteger using a string the decryption does not return the original BigInteger. 
Here is the code I am using to generate my keys and encrypt/decrypt.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int keySize = 32;

    BigInteger prime1 = new BigInteger(keySize / 2, 100, new SecureRandom());
    BigInteger prime2 = new BigInteger(keySize / 2, 100, new SecureRandom());

    BigInteger n = prime1.multiply(prime2); 
    BigInteger totient = prime1.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(prime2.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));

    //create the private key
    BigInteger e;
    do e = new BigInteger(totient.bitLength(), new SecureRandom());
    while (e.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) <= 0 || e.compareTo(totient) >= 0 || !e.gcd(totient).equals(BigInteger.ONE));

    //create public key
    BigInteger d = e.modInverse(totient);


    String original = "Hello World!";

    BigInteger enc = new BigInteger(original.getBytes());
    System.out.println("Original: " + enc.toString());

    //encrypt
    enc = enc.modPow(e, n);

    //decrypt
    BigInteger dec = enc;
    dec = dec.modPow(d, n);
    System.out.println("Result: " + dec.toString());
}
```

As I said, if I initialize enc to an integer value, say 10, my results would be...

```
Original: 10
Result: 10
```

However, when I initialize to a string, as in the code above, my results come out like this...

```
Original: 22405534230753928650781647905
Result: 1828948854
```

Did I implement my encryption wrong or is there something I am missing in converting the string to a BigInteger to encrypt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Did I implement my encryption wrong

Yes.

It looks like you're implementing RSA with a 32-bit `keySize`. This limits the size of your message to 32 bits as well; the message you're trying to encrypt is much larger than this.

Comment: Thank you, I kept the number small so I could easily view the numbers. I did not realize that could effect the encryption.